# Flutter can't detect 'model.tflite' file from assets folder (FileNotFoundException)

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

### Background

I'm making a fruit classification app using flutter on android studio. The app will work as follows:

1. Take a picture with the camera.
2. Predict the type of fruit in the picture.

To do step (2), I'm using a **'model.tflite'** file that was exported from [teachable machine](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image). I'm also using the [tflite](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite) plugin for flutter.

## The Problem

When my program tries to predict the image, I get the following message in the console:

```
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296): Failed to handle method call
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported value: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/assets/model.tflite
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMessageCodec.writeValue(StandardMessageCodec.java:278)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.StandardMethodCodec.encodeErrorEnvelope(StandardMethodCodec.java:69)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler$1.error(MethodChannel.java:236)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:98)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:226)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:631)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:197)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    E/MethodChannel#tflite( 7296):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
    I/flutter ( 7296):  
    I/flutter ( 7296): ERROR: PlatformException(error, Unsupported value: java.io.FileNotFoundException: flutter_assets/assets/model.tflite, null)
```

Flutter can't seem to find the **model.tflite** file from my assets folder!

### What I've tried

- I have triple checked the indentations in `pubspec.yaml` (below). The file paths and names of directories are also correct.

```
    flutter:
      assets:
        - assets/labels.txt
        - assets/model.tflite
```

- I have read the [tflite docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/tflite/latest/).
- I've downloaded the **model.tflite** as a floating point type and quantized type.
- I have tried renaming the **model.tflite** file (you could tell I was getting desperate).
- I have also tried changing certain parameters within my code. Below is the function where the error seems to be happening - it is called whenever the user takes a picture.

```
      Future classifyImage() async {
        try{
          String res = await Tflite.loadModel(
              model: 'assets/model.tflite',
              labels: 'assets/labels.txt',
              numThreads: 1,
              isAsset: true,
              useGpuDelegate: true
          );
          print(res);
          var recognitions = await Tflite.runModelOnImage(
            path: _image.path,
            imageMean: 117.0,
            imageStd: 1.0,
            numResults: 1,
            threshold: 0.5,
            asynch: true,
          );
          _recognitions = recognitions;
          await Tflite.close();
        } catch (error){
          print(' ');
          print('ERROR: $error');
        }
```

- Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjH5R.png) of my project directories.
- I have also tried flutter clean, quitting android studio and restarting the project.

PLEASE HELP! I'm currently waiting for someone to float from the heavens and magically fix my problem. I'm also a beginner to flutter, so any general suggestions to my code would be greatly appreciated :-).

Thank you.

Comment: (Just as a sanity check, did you stop the app and restart/rebuild?)

Comment: Silly question but you have actually got a file named model.tflite in your project's assets folder?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I definitely do have a model.tflite file in my assets folder. I have also restarted the app and used flutter clean.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead and open the android / app / build.gradle file and add the following code inside the android block.

```
aaptOptions {
    noCompress 'tflite'
    noCompress 'lite'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I went on my project the next day and the error doesn't seem to be coming up. Not too sure what happened...
Perhaps it was something to do with my laptop?